# NGINX not working other than /usr/share/nginx directory

Tags: nginx, centos7

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Server: nginx/1.12.2

when I set document root /usr/share/nginx/{any_directory} it works,

but when I set document root to /var/www/{any_dir} it throws 403 error

**file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost localhost.localdomain;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html; #orking
        #root /usr/share/nginx/test; #works_fine
        #root /var/www/iplog/public_html; #thorws 403 error

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

and

**file:  /etc/nginx/sites-available/iplog.domain.tld.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/iplog/public_html; #thorws 403 error
  #root /usr/share/nginx/test; #works_fine

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name iplog.domain.tld;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

[**access.log added**](https://gist.github.com/an-amin/a6a653f601329fa3c3dade7dfa4c02d5#file-access-log)

[**all configuration files are given here**](https://gist.github.com/an-amin/a6a653f601329fa3c3dade7dfa4c02d5)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please include your Nginx configuration files as part of your question, as it makes it easier for people to read and means the question is useful to others in the future.

Comment: The answer could be file permissions for the user Nginx is running as.

Comment: performed `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/iplog` **and** `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/iplog` but not working, still throwning **403 error**.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have SELinux running and you need to add permissions for nginx to access the other folder.

Edit: See also this answer on SELinux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228202

Answer (score 0):

Check access log it should give you more details,It may be possible that /var/www/{any_dir}  is owned by root and nginx is unable to access that file.

Comment: performed `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/iplog` **and** `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/iplog` but not working, still throwning **403 error**.

Comment: nginx does not run with nginx user it runs with www-data.

Comment: `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’`

Comment: @amit singh It doesn't matter which user nginx runs with as long as you set correct permissions. According to his configuration it runs with the username "nginx"

Comment: @amitsingh, access.log file added.

Comment: what is extension of file. try access any particular file

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct folder permissions.
The nginx-user has to have read and execute permissions.

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/iplog/public_html
```

should do the trick. If nginx also needs access to the files the parent folder iplog you can do

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/iplog
```

Comment: performed `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/iplog` **and** `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/iplog` but not working, still throwning **403 error**.

Comment: What are your users and permissions to this point? I mean for `/var` and `/var/www`? Also do you have an index file inside public_html?

Comment: `/var/www/iplog`

Comment: what do you want to tell me with this? Your webserver-user must be able to traverse from / to your web root, he needs read and execute permissions for that (5). So you need 755 on /var, 755 on /var/www, 755 on /var/www/iplog and 755 on /var/www/iplog/public_html. Also, is there an **index**-file? Try adding `autoindex on;` to your `location /`-segment.

Comment: did, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  There is another security of some sort. Found my solution with this command: `getenforce`

disable SELinux until next reboot:

```
$> sudo setenforce 0
```

Permanent change is done here: `/etc/selinux/config`